# How to compile/install mplayer on MacOS with subtitle support?

Tags: command-line, video, mplayer

In order to play video files with a sub title file on MacOS 10.13.6 on the command line: How to install `mplayer` so that I am able to use subtitles?

I tried the following suggestion made in [some other post](https://superuser.com/questions/1364372/how-to-make-mplayer-use-subtitles):

```
brew uninstall mplayer
brew reinstall freetype
brew reinstall fontconfig
brew install --build-from-source mplayer
```

The last command provoked an error:

```
Error: Xcode alone is not sufficient on High Sierra.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

and so I did install the `Command Line Tools`. Then I repeated the `mplayer` install command. It was installed with the following configure line:

```
./configure --cc=clang --host-cc=clang --disable-cdparanoia --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.3.0 --disable-x11
```

But then running the command as follows

```
mplayer  testvideo.mkv  -sub SubTest.srt
```

with the content of `SubTest.srt` as follows:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
<font face="Arial" size="50" color="#425aa0"><b>TEST TEXT</b></font>
```

does NOT show any subtitle, nor any error.

The output of `brew info mplayer`is:

```
mplayer: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
UNIX movie player
https://mplayerhq.hu/
/usr/local/Cellar/mplayer/1.3.0 (11 files, 28.8MB) *
  Built from source on 2019-01-11 at 07:40:20
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mplayer.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: yasm ✔
Optional: libcaca ✘, libdvdnav ✘, libdvdread ✘
==> Options
--with-libcaca
    Build with libcaca support
--with-libdvdnav
    Build with libdvdnav support
--with-libdvdread
    Build with libdvdread support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 1,198 (30 days), 3,569 (90 days), 15,129 (365 days)
install_on_request: 1,140 (30 days), 3,408 (90 days), 14,307 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

What else can I try? I rather would not like to install and use a virtual box ...

Comment: You could try iina https://iina.io which uses mpv which is a fork of mplayer2 and MPlayer. If cmmand line only then mpv might be enough

Comment: Installing `mpv` is some kind of solution, but it broke thw working of `mplayer` and `avconv`. I had to re-install `mplayer` and `avconv` to have them use again. Stupid MacOS...